# Como contar quantos registros existem em uma relação OneToMany?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Possuo duas tabelas que estão se relacionando no formato OneToMany, exemplo: possuo um registro da tabela A que se relaciona com 1 ou mais registros na tabela B. Estou tentando fazer uma query que me retorne quantos registros da tabela B estão relacionados com o mesmo registro na tabela A.

Estou tentando desta forma:

```
select count (A.Chave) from A inner join B on (A.Chave = B.Chave)
```

Da forma que estou tentando a query retorna o numero de registros da tabela B que possuem relacionamento com qualquer registro da tabela A.

De que forma posso resolver isto ?

Comment: está usando `sql-server`?

Comment: @rLinhares Sim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que deva fazer a contagem "ao contrário":

```
SELECT b.chave, COUNT(b.chave)
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.chave = b.chave
GROUP BY b.chave
```

Como precisa saber quantas ocorrências existem na tabela `B`, traga essa contagem no `count`,